# ¡Segundo concurso del 2016! - Fechas editadas

Tags: discusión, medallas, anuncios

### **Concurso #2 - Ganar las medallas de Altruista, Iluminado, y Autodidacta.**

Vamos a mas de la mitad del año y es tiempo de ofrecer otro concurso. Este sera el segundo de otros en este año así que pónganse las pilas que vamos a comenzar.

[image: mucho poder]

Durante el 18 a 31 de julio del 2016, daremos una camiseta oficial de Stack Overflow en español a los que consigan las medallas mencionadas.

Los ganadores deberán tener en su posesión estas medallas para ser considerados como ganadores.

Se deberá:

- ganar/tener la medalla de **Altruista**: Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en la pregunta de otra persona
- ganar/tener la medalla de **Iluminado**: Primero en responder, y respuesta aceptada con una puntuación de 10 o más
- ganar/tener la medalla de **Autodidacta**: Responder tu propia pregunta con puntuación de 3 o más

Las camisas vienen en tamaños Chica -> Extra Grande y también las tenemos en corte femenino. Para ver como son las camisas, pueden ver [nuestro canal de YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C1soDvDYno) donde los panelistas y yo las estamos "modelando" mientras participamos en el webcast.

Para más información sobre las medallas, [favor de leer aquí.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

**¡Empezamos ya!**

Comment: Vamo a participar!

Comment: De desarrolladores a modelos, esta comunidad si te hace crecer

Comment: Y los que ganaron la anterior vez todavía siguen esperando que lleguen sus camisetas :C

Comment: @dwarandae todos los ganadores del concurso anterior fueron contactados y los premios enviados ;)

Comment: Hola, ¿se puede ganar la medalla de Altruista iniciando una recompensa con la opción *"la pregunta no recibió suficiente atención"*? ¿como se otorga manualmente?. Por cierto, fantástica idea la de los concursos, participar en S.O. se hace más divertido #loQueSeaPorUnaCamiseta ;-)

Comment: @rsciriano para aprender sobre las recompensas, [favor de leer aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)  - ¡y por cierto, excelente hashtag!

Comment: ¿Se podría ampliar un poco el plazo? 14 días parecen pocos para tanta medalla ;P

Comment: Por cierto, parece que algo no está bien con la medalla "Autodidacta" o con su descripción. La gané por [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/622/250) pero no por [esta otra](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10519/250). Las dos son respuestas a mi propia pregunta con más de 3 puntos.

Comment: Iluminado esta mas dificil que abrir visual studio 2015 con ram de 512 Mb... yo queria la cameseeta :c

Comment: Pero.... yo ya tenía la medalla de altruista y sólo se otorga 1 vez, no? es sólo para la **primera** recompensa que se otorga, si ya tengo esa medalla y fuera del plazo que indicas, no puedo optar al concurso? :( (Curiosamente hoy mismo he dado otro bounty manualmente a una pregunta, pero no creo que me vuelvan a dar la medalla ya que sólo se da 1 vez...)

Comment: @MiquelColl He corregido los requisitos de las medallas.  ¡Favor de leer al anuncio de nuevo!

Comment: @juanm bieeeen! Ya puedo participar :D

Comment: Muy buena la idea de los concursos. Hace que se motiven más los usuarios del sitio, pero para motivar aún más a los participantes por qué no regalan al ganador un poco de reputación también? (es solo una sugerencia)

Comment: ¿Los que ya tenemos una camiseta podemos participar en este concurso?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¡por supuesto!

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro a coleccionar todas las camisetas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Hemos llegado al final del segundo concurso! Felicidades a todos los que participaron. No se sientan vencidos que tendremos más oportunidades de ganar en el futuro.

Los ganadores de este concurso son:

### [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro)

### [astrojuanlu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/74/astrojuanlu)

¡Felicidades a los dos! Favor de mandarme un mensaje con su dirección y la talla de camisa que quieran recibir.

Hasta la próxima...

Comment: YAY! Enhorabuena @astrojuanlu!

Comment: Felicidades @AlvaroMontoro! Es un poco raro que astrojuanlu no haya publicado anda des de el 21 de junio pero lo haya ganado haha, ¡felicidades igualmente!

Comment: felicitaciones hermanos :D

Comment: Yo tampoco sé cómo ha ocurrido esto pero estoy muy contento de haber ganado la camiseta, me servirá para hacer publicidad en mis círculos :D ¡Felicidades @AlvaroMontoro!

Comment: Haha :) ¡felicidades!

Comment: Bueno, esta vez creo que estaba muy complicado (desde que vi las 3 "metas" del concurso imaginaba que sería así), además curioso el caso de astrojuanlu, en todo caso: el que gana es el que goza!

Answer (score 2):

Como [pueden ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened), la medalla de Iluminado no se ha ganado todavía.  Extenderemos el concurso for 2 semanas más para dar mas tiempo a los participantes.

¡Tienen hasta el **15 de agosto** para completar los requisitos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo, no se otorgó 28 veces ya???

Comment: @Mariano Cierto, 28 medallas se han ganado pero no durante en tiempo requerido por el concurso. No han habido medallas de esta categoría ganadas durante el mes de julio. [Ve aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened)

Comment: Ah, está bien... entonces no es `ganar/tener la medalla de..` sino `ganar la medalla de..`?

Comment: Excelente punto.  Sigue siendo **ganar/tener** pero como no ha habido alguien que la gane todavía, he dado más tiempo para los que no la tienen.

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclararlo Juan!.. Disculpá la insistencia, la verdad lo leía y no podía ser... incluso me preguntaba si no se habían confundido [iluminado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) con [iluminadoR](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/92/illuminator)

Comment: ...Y ya tenés alguien que la ganó... No me vas a creer, pero no  la buscaba. Encima creo que con el peor de mis posts

Comment: En una de mis preguntas :D

Comment: Entonces, yo he ganado la medalla Altruista y ya tenía las otras dos. ¿Debo ganar las otras dos de nuevo?¿sólo una?¿o cómo va eso? Porque me he perdido con el comentario de arriba

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Según entendí, ya la ganaste. Y extendieron el tiempo dándole la oportunidad a nuevos usuarios.