# ¿Cómo ven si usamos la etiqueta "artículo" para las publicaciones en meta que no son preguntas?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, meta

## Propuesta

Usemos [artículo](/questions/tagged/art%c3%adculo) para iniciar publicaciones en Meta que no son preguntas pero que son similares a una publicación en un blog.

> Si estas de acuerdo con esto, vota positivo, si discrepas completamente vota negativo, si tienes sugerencias o contra-propuestas, agrégalas como respuesta, si hace falta clarificación agrega un comentario, si consideras que puedes mejorar esta publicación, edítala.

## Explicación

En Meta las publicaciones deben incluir una de cuatro posibles etiquetas obligatorias [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n),[soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte),[bug](/questions/tagged/bug),[característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva), los moderadores diamantados tienen la posibilidad de agregar etiquetas restringidas como [destacado](/questions/tagged/destacado) y la comunidad puede agregar la etiquetas creadas por usuarios con el privilegio de crear etiquetas.

Como cuento con el privilegio de crear etiquetas nuevas, he creado la etiqueta propuesta pero antes de proceder a aplicar a más publicaciones creo que en este caso lo más apropiado es consultar antes de agregarla a más "preguntas", ya que en el pasado se han realizado propuestas un tanto similares y "no han prosperado".

Entre las propuestas previas en Meta SE está [We're Implementing an "announcement" Tag for Direct Communication From the Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290662/289691) publicada por [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) quien es Director de Gestión de la Comunidad de Stack Overflow. Dicha propuesta tiene un balance de 32 puntos negativos. En lo que difiere esta propuesta de aquella es que aquí no se trata de una etiqueta de comunicación directa "del equipo", o cual podría ser un caso muy específico, sino que estoy proponiendo una etiqueta que pueda ser agregada por la comunidad.

Hace no mucho tiempo los sitios de SE tenían un blog de la comunidad pero esta características fue retirada. Los detalles en [We will no longer be hosting Blog Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741/289691).

Las preguntas en Meta con la [artículo](/questions/tagged/art%c3%adculo) serían eximidas de usar el formato pregunta-respuesta del modelo de Stack Overflow pero deberán corresponder a la temática de Meta, por ejemplo, podría ser usada para traducciones de artículos de blog publicados originalmente en el blog de Stack Overflow en inglés.

## Ejemplos de preguntas que no son preguntas

### Del Gerente de la Comunidad y otros empleados de Stack Overflow

#### Tipo blog

Las siguientes publicaciones son candidatas a tener el etiqueta [artículo](/questions/tagged/art%c3%adculo)

- [¡Bienvenidos a este su sitio!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146/65)
- [¡Segundo concurso del 2016! - Fechas editadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/685/65)
- [Objetivos del 2017 - Primera Parte (1)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1275/65)
- [Objetivos del 2017 - Segunda Parte (2)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1314/65)
- [Pruebas técnicas de la red de Stack Exchange - 3 de mayo 12:00 AM UTC](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1871/65)

#### Tipo encuesta

Las siguientes publicaciones NO son candidatas a tener [artículo](/questions/tagged/art%c3%adculo):

- [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/65)

### De la comunidad

#### Tipo blog

Las siguientes publicaciones son candidatas a tener y conservar la etiqueta [artículo](/questions/tagged/art%c3%adculo):

- [Si vas a responder tu pregunta, hazlo antes de publicar la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/182/65)
- [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2209/65)
- [Una Teoría de Moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/65)

## Relacionado

- [¿Debe ser toda pregunta en meta una pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1926/65)
- [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2093/65)

Comment: Lo que aquí se propone es una realidad que ya existe. Reconocer esa realidad con una etiqueta es lo razonable.